# Email Won't Send in Classic ASP, But I Never Get An Error

Tags: email, asp-classic

I am building a website where people can sign up for a service. When they submit their information, it should create an `XMLHttpRequest` and send the data to an .asp file on the server. The ASP should then email the data to me and email the user a confirmation email.

This is the code that sends the request (written in JavaScript):

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            window.location = 'thankyou.html';
    }
};
xhttp.open("POST", "sendData.asp", true)
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", document.forms["SignupForm"])
xhttp.send("fname="+fname+"&lname="+lname+"&email="+email+"&width="+width+"&length="+length+"&depth="+depth+"&crnStp="+crnStp+"&jets="+jets+"&mirror="+mirror+"&rails="+rails)
```

This is the classic ASP that then processes it:

```
response.expires=-1
Dim fname
Dim lname
Dim email
Dim width
Dim length
Dim depth
Dim crnStp
Dim jets
Dim mirror
Dim rails
fname=request.querystring("fname")
lname=request.querystring("lname")
email=request.querystring("email")
width=request.querystring("width")
length=request.querystring("length")
depth=request.querystring("depth")
crnStp=request.querystring("crnStp")
jets=request.querystring("jets")
mirror=request.querystring("mirror")
rails=request.querystring("rails")
Dim msg
Set msg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
msg.Subject = "NewPoolSignUp"
msg.From = "robot@example.com"
msg.To = "myEmail@example.com"
msg.TextBody = fname & "," & lname & "," & email & "," & width & "," & length & "," & depth & "," & crnStp & "," & jets & "," & mirror & "," & rails
msg.Send
set msg = nothing
Dim msg
Set msg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
msg.Subject = "Thank You For Joining Big Splash!"
msg.From = "robot@example.com"
msg.To = email
msg.CreateMHTMLBody = "https://example.com/sf/confEmail.html" 'An html page created, body of email should be = to page
msg.Send
set msg = nothing
response.write("done")
```

Please be courteous when giving answers, as I am new to ASP. All of the code above is from other sources (although I modified file names and directories and things like that).

As I said above, the code does not give an error but I never recieve the email. Could someone please help me with this?

**EDIT:** The above code does give me an error. (I had accidentally put `Response.End` in it.) I removed the `Response.End` statement and added configuration settings for ports, smtp server, username, password, etc.  I still get an error.

I also get an alert from my Gmail account (the account being sent from) saying that a sign-in was blocked. I might need to change Gmail settings to allow the ASP to access the account.

**EDIT 2:** I changed the Gmail settings and I am recieving the email. But it still generates an error, and when I look at the contents of the email, it contains only commas and not the variables. I think there is something wrong with the concatenation in the `msg.TextBody = …` command.

Comment: Classic ASP uses VBScript which is typeless and doesn’t support variables declared using `Dim variable As Type` instead, use `Dim variable`.

Comment: @Lankymart, Thanks for the tip, but I tried it and it did not change the result. I'll use typeless declarations in the future.

Comment: I edited the above code for typeless declarations.

Comment: Take a look at method 3 on this page.  On IIS7 and above I've found that I need the config section even when I'm using a local SMTP server.
http://www.powerasp.net/content/new/sending_email_cdosys.asp

Comment: To add to that comment.  It could be that the email is sending but not arriving.  Emails often fail to get through if the information in the message header looks suspect, which could well be the case if you're using an SMTP server which isn't normally associated with the email address

Comment: @John, check the edit I saved.

Comment: I changed the Gmail settings and I am recieving the email. But it still generates an error, and when I look at the contents of the email, it contains only commas and not the variables. I think there is something wrong with the concatenation in the `msg.TextBody = …` command.

Comment: `xhttp.open("POST", "sendData.asp", true)` - POST is equivalent to sending the data in a form, and you're using `Request.Querystring`.  To retrieve form data you need to use `Request.Form`, or you can just use `Request` which will retrieve either querystring or form data.

Comment: (Continued from above comment) … Or maybe there is something wrong with the `request.querystring()` command.

Comment: Reload the page and see my last comment

Comment: What concerned me more is the fact you had clear syntax errors with the use of `As` in your declarations but the code didn't error. You don't have an `On Error Resume Next` floating around you didn't post do you?

Comment: @John, I tried both `Request.Form` and `Request` but I still get only commas. I have already verified that when the request is sent from the JavaScript code, all of the variables have a value in them, so it has to be an ASP problem. By the way, even though I recieve the first email, the code still generates an error and I never recieve the second email.

Comment: @Lankymart, No. There is no `On Error` command whatsoever. As you can see, I am now using typeless declarations and it still generates the error. Read the other comments for further info.

Comment: @AlwaysBeProgramming I was refering to your original comment in the question - *"the code does not give an error but I never recieve the email"*. What concerned me was with your original code it must have errored the Classic ASP preprocessor wouldn't allow it to continue due to the VBScript syntax error generated by the `As` in your declarations.

Comment: Lankymart, Ok. Thanks.

Comment: `xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", document.forms["SignupForm"])` is not correct. Check by commenting out that line.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ, what is the appropriate syntax? Commenting this out does not change the result. I still get the error.

Comment: See : [XMLHttpRequest.send() Example: POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send#Example_POST)

Comment: @SearchAndResQ, What are you saying? I understand that my `setRequestHeader` code uses incorrect syntax, but this does not clearly explain the correct syntax. I don't think that `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` is the right value to pass to the second parameter, is it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your mail server, otherwise your code won't know where to send the email from.

```
msg.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = x
msg.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "your.exchange.server"
msg.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = x
msg.Configuration.Fields.Update
msg.Send
```

Comment: I already have this. See the first edit section of my question.